# Pagiantor on a search function

Tags: django, function, paginator

I tried to add a Paginator of 5 posts to the current function but I always have developed with the ListView functions, in which is way easier to implement a pagiantor. Any suggestion?

```py
    def search(request):
            query = request.GET.get("q", None)
            qs = DeathAd.objects.all()
            if query is not None:
                qs = qs.annotate(
                    full_name = Concat('nome', Value(' '), 'cognome'),
                    full_cognome = Concat('cognome', Value(' '), 'nome')
                ).filter(
                    Q(nome__icontains=query) |
                    Q(cognome__icontains=query) |
                    Q(full_name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(full_cognome__icontains=query)
                )
    
            context = {
                "object_list": qs,
            }
            template = "search.html"
            return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Adding pagination and search functionality to a ListView is probably the easiest way

Comment: Yes but unfortunately here I have to deal with a normal function :)